# length property of array not working properly in for loop

Tags: javascript

> I don't understand what is the problem here, when i put  `array.length` inside for loop it's giving wrong length.

```js
let x = 'w3resource'
let y = x.split('');
let output = [];

// let len = y.length;
for(let i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
  let z = y.pop();
  output.push(z);
}

let alfa = output.join('');

console.log(alfa);
```

> Now when i put it outside it's working correctly.

```js
let x = 'w3resource'
let y = x.split('');
let output = [];

let len = y.length;
for(let i = 0; i < len; i++){
  let z = y.pop();
  output.push(z);
}

let alfa = output.join('');

console.log(alfa);
```

> Please explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, `y.length` is re-evaluated on every iteration. Since you're popping elements from the array, the array gets smaller on every iteration, and the value of `y.length` decrements by 1.

This is why you only have 5 characters in the output of your first snippet.

```
Iteration  |  i  |  y.length
-----------|-----|----------
    1      |  0  |    10
    2      |  1  |     9
    3      |  3  |     8
    4      |  4  |     7
    5      |  5  |     6
```

Answer (score 3):

Because everytime you call `pop` method y.pop() , the length of an array changes (y.length).

There are some methods in javascript which mutate objects internally upon calling them, such as `pop` and `push`

Answer (score 1):

first run:

```
i = 0; y = ["w","3","r","e","s","o","u","r","c","e"]; y.length = 10;
y.pop() => y =["w","3","r","e","s","o","u","r","c"]; y.length =9;
```

second run:

```
i = 1; y.length = 9;
...
```

continue like that the length of y array get smaller so its why you got result = 'ecruo';

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) is mutable method in JavaScript.

So, when you `pop()` out elements from array, the array `y` is updated.

For loop mechanism

1. i == 0 and y == 10, `i< y.length`  condition true, `z = y.pop()` and  `y.length` becomes 9
2. i == 1 and y == 9, `i< y.length`  condition true, `z = y.pop()` and  `y.length` becomes 8
3. i == 2 and y == 8, `i< y.length`  condition true, `z = y.pop()` and  `y.length` becomes 7
4. i == 3 and y == 7, `< y.length`  condition true, `z = y.pop()` and  `y.length` becomes 6
5. i == 4 and y == 6, `i< y.length`  condition true, `z = y.pop()` and  `y.length` becomes 5
6. i == 5 and y == 5, `i< y.length`  condition false, loop exits.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x = 'w3resource'
let y = x.split('');
let output = [];

// let len = y.length;
for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  let z = y[i];
  output.push(z);
}

let alfa = output.join('');
console.log(output);
```

**y.pop()** function method **removes the last element** from an array and returns that element, so whenever you called it the variable y will have less length than previous. so your code is perfect just need to correction at **y.pop()**.